# How to find impulse response of the input signal in Python?

Tags: python, impulse-response

I had to read input .wav audio file first, then add Gaussian white noise to the input audio signal and I've finished that part. Now I have to add a channel model whose impulse response is:

```
h[n] = [−0.015, 0.058, −0.350, 1.000, −0.350, 0.058, −0.005]
```

[image]

This is what the communication system should look like. I have to add this impulse response and then plot the output signal
but I don't really understand how to do that. I've tried this using scipy:

```
system = ([1.0],[-0.015,0.058,-0.350,1.000,-0.350,0.058,-0.005])
t2, y = signal.impulse(system)
plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(t2, y)
```

But the output doesn't look right

Input signal
[image]

[image]

Impulse response output

Comment: A _signal_ does not have an impulse response.  An impulse response itself is a signal, but it is the response of a specific sort of _system_ to a specific sort of signal.  To add to the confusion, you don't reference your input signal in your code _at all_.  Could you please _edit your question_ to state (a) what you're actually doing, and (b) what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I am just trying to understand this for an exam. I had to read input .wav audio file first, then add Gaussian white noise to the input audio signal and I've finished that part. Now I have to add a channel model whose impulse response is: h[n] = [−0.015, 0.058, −0.350, 1.000, −0.350, 0.058, −0.005]  but I don't really understand how to do that.

Comment: Oops -- I left out the part where I checked to see that you're a newbie and then tell you to _edit your question_ with that information so that it is complete.  It's a Stackexchange thing -- unlike other forums, we want complete questions and complete answers, without bits & pieces buried in the comments.

Comment: While you're going to the effort of editing the question, you should also look at the documentation for the signal.impulse function -- look at what you're giving it as input, and ask yourself if you're describing a system whose impulse response is as you specify?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question, I hope it's understandble now. I also read the documentation, in fact I'm still reading but not quite sure how to add this channel block, I need to add the output of this impulse response to the previous signal, right,but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so your assignment is:

1. Read an input .wav file, let's call it $x_1[n]$
2. Add White Gaussian noise: $x[n] = x_1[n] + \nu[n]$

You've done these steps, I'll assume correctly.

---

3. Pass this noisy signal through a system with given impulse response $h[n]$. That's the part you're having trouble with.

Look at the documentation for [scipy.signal.impulse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.impulse.html): the first thing you'll see is

> Impulse response of continuous-time system.

First, your system isn't continuous, it's discrete, and second, **you already know the impulse response**:  $h[n]$.

Let's back-track a little bit. I'll assume you have *some* theoretical background on what a digital system is and how it can take an input and produce an output. I'll write it out here for completeness, it's called **convolution**:

$$y[n] = x[n] \star h[n] \tag{1}$$ where $y[n]$ is the **output** to the system with **impulse response** $h[n]$, when fed with **input $x[n]$.**

You have $x[n]$ and $h[n]$ already, and you're looking to compute $y[n]$, so you're looking for a way to implement (1). Here comes [scipy.signal.lfilter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) which does just that. The documentation starts with:

> Filter data along one-dimension with an IIR or FIR filter.
>
> [...]
>
> Parameters
>
> b: array_like The numerator coefficient vector in a 1-D
> sequence.
>
> a: array_like The denominator coefficient vector in a 1-D sequence. If
> a[0] is not 1, then both a and b are normalized by a[0].
>
> x: array_like
> An N-dimensional input array.

Your system is what we call a [FIR filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response), so it does not have a denominator (to be more precise, its denominator is $1$), and its numerator is equal to the Finite Impulse Reponse $h[n]$

To implement (1):

```
y = signal.lfilter(h,1,x)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a great explanation